# Hey Guys, I'm trying to learn how to create something like the attached image in blender for product work

Tags: polycount

Is there anyone out there willing to please help me or point me to a good tutorial. please[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htk4S.png)

Comment: Show your work so far. If you have Ø to show, I suggest you create a cylinder with proportional edit.  Please look on youtube for a tutorial for creating a bottle.

Comment: Tutorial Series.  Please see all of it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS. Typically this site frowns on tutorial requests.  There is a list of learning resources that you can search on this BSE site.

Comment: This is a tutorial request and not a specific question. Tutorial requests are considered off topic on this site.

Comment: Also, please use **meaningful** headlines. Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please). It contains lots of information about how to ask good questions and receive good answers.

Answer (score -1):

Two good tutorials, I would go with the one on Lynda if you have a library card you can watch it for free and the teacher is awesome.
https://www.lynda.com/Blender-tutorials/Product-Shots-Blender/160819-2.html?srchtrk=index%3a1%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3ablender+product+shots%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2

Free version on YouTube that's still pretty good:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBtWfVkghow

Also, the first one is in Blender 2.7 and the second one is in Blender 2.8 so that may help you make a choice as well.

Comment: A brief summary of what they do perhaps?

Comment: Please read [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)